# RxJava combine multiple observables do sth after all done

Tags: rx-java, rx-android

I've got a method which should reload DB using multiple observables. After all it should call method setupPlace(selecetedPlace), but only once. Each observable returns different object (void, object, listOfObjects).

```
private void reloadDatabaseFromRest(final Place selectedPlace, final Event selectedEvent) throws ParseException {
    Observable.concat(DatabaseManager.getInstance().clearDatabase(),
            mPlaceUseCase.getPlacesListFromRestObservable()
                    .filter(places -> places != null && !places.isEmpty())
                    .doOnNext(places -> mPlaceUseCase.savePlacesToRepository(places)),
            mPlaceUseCase.saveSelectedPlace(selectedPlace),
            mEventUseCase.getEvenListObservableFromRest(selectedPlace.getId())
                    .doOnNext(eventList -> mEventUseCase.saveEventsToRepository(eventList)),
            mEventUseCase.saveSelectedEventObservable(selectedEvent))
            .takeLast(1)
            .subscribe(o -> mSplashScreenUI.setupPlace(selectedPlace));
}
```

But this method is doing subsribe() only on last observable and others are not invoked (am I right?). I tried using filters, zip and making stupid if(o instanceOf ArrayList) clause, but it is wrong way. Can someone help me, please?

Comment: `concat` should invoke all observables, in order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Completable` type. Completable just informs subscriber that the stream is finished.

Wrap every observable you need to subscribe into a Completable with `Completable.fromObservable()` and then merge ( parallel start ) them with `Completable.merge()` or concat them ( in series one after the other ) with `Completable.concat`.

***Note:*** make sure that all of the observables you wrap into Completable will call onComplete and so are not endless streams.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much @koperko! It works like a charm and this is exactly what I needed.
During rewriting method I noticed that first Observable emits 6 items (clearDatabase()), so I wrapped it into Completable and it works! 
Instead of using concat() I used flatMap():

```
private void reloadDatabaseFromRest(final Place selectedPlace, final Event selectedEvent) {
    Completable.fromObservable(
            DatabaseManager.getInstance().clearDatabase()
                    .flatMap(aVoidDB -> mPlaceUseCase.getPlacesListFromRestObservable().filter(places -> places != null && !places.isEmpty()))
                    .flatMap(places -> mPlaceUseCase.savePlacesToRepository(places))
                    .flatMap(aVoidPlace -> mPlaceUseCase.saveSelectedPlace(selectedPlace))
                    .flatMap(aVoidSelectedPlace -> {
                        try {
                            return mEventUseCase.getEvenListObservableFromRest(selectedPlace.getId());
                        } catch (ParseException e) {
                            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                            return null;
                        }
                    })
                    .filter(eventList -> eventList != null)
                    .flatMap(eventList -> mEventUseCase.saveEventsToRepository(eventList))
                    .flatMap(aVoidEvents -> mEventUseCase.saveSelectedEventObservable(selectedEvent)))
            .subscribe(() -> {
                mSplashScreenUI.setupPlace(selectedPlace);
            });
}
```